# What is the best Solution for Modal in web but not modal in Mobile React

Tags: reactjs

I am using React Js for web development and for the Login component I am using Modal, because of the design I have to change the modal into part of the web (not modal or full screen modal with header) in Mobile version (less than 560px), I think I can use window.innerwidth to check if web is opened in mobile or not and depending on whether it mobile, Modal or Component will be shown. but is it Correct way? There are many responsive websites that requires has modal but not modal on mobile version. How they have solved this problem?
Thank you

Comment: We still have modals but with full screen on mobile devices

Comment: in that case how we are gonna pop up the header and footer?

Comment: What do you mean by popping up the header and footer? A modal is already on top of everything to make users focus on modal content. It's a similar case for modals on mobile devices

Comment: Yes I need to header and footer at the top and bottom and in the middle part login form suppose to be there in mobile version